# Kick off MAGMI via command line and login automatically

Tags: login, magmi

Is it possible to kick off MAGMI via the command line and have it automatically log into MAGMI (ie suppress the usual login prompt)

eg I'm invoking IE from a C# app and passing in:

http://localhost:1234/magmi/web/magmi_run.php?mode=update&profile=MyMAGMIProfile&engine=magmi_productimportengine:Magmi_ProductImportEngine&CSV:filename=../../data/upload/muk_000000045_price.csv

but it then comes up with the Login Prompt:

[image: MAGMI login prompt]

Can this prompt be avoided somehow?

[UPDATE]

From C# I've tried this:

```
...
            var str = "my password";
            var sc = new System.Security.SecureString();


            foreach (char c in str)
            {
                sc.AppendChar(c);
            }

            try
            {

                using (var process = Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "-nomerge " + completeURL, "maguser676", sc, ""))
                {
                    // Capture output...
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
            }
...
```

But raises an error saying that the user name or password is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Now, this is not exactly the best place for a C#-related question, so I can't exactly tell whether this works for you in your environment but one approach can be to specify the username and password together with the URL like so:

```
var completeURL = "http://maguser676:mypassword@localhost:1234/magmi/web/magmi_run.php?mode=update&profile=MyMAGMIProfile&engine=magmi_productimportengine:Magmi_ProductImportEngine&CSV:filename=../../data/upload/muk_000000045_price.csv";
```

Second option would be to comment a part of the authentication behavior and restrict the access to MAGMI by an IP address without further authentication (obviously, you should not do this if the C#-application is executed by a machine without a static IP address and/or there are other reasons why the IP address is not to be rated **secure** e.g. due to the networks topology it is assigned to):

**magmi/.htaccess** (create this new file)

```
# Allow access to MAGMI GUI by the following IP address only
<RequireAll>
    Require ip 123.234.123.234
</RequireAll>
```

**magmi/web/security.php** (comment the if/else condition)
Note: There may be several places from where you could prevent MAGMI from asking for authentication, but that one was the first that came in my mind:

```
<?php
require_once(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))."/inc/magmi_auth.php");
function authenticate($username="",$password=""){

    $auth = new Magmi_Auth($username,$password);

    return $auth->authenticate();
}

// WWW-Auth disabled since we authenticate based on the IP address only.
/*if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate:Basic realm="Magmi"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo 'You must be logged in to use Magmi';
    die();
} else {
    if (!authenticate($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'],$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'])){
        header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Magmi"');
        header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
        echo 'You must be logged in to use Magmi';
        die();
    }

}*/
```

Ultimately, as a third option you could execute MAGMI by a cron job on the webserver (or by creating a Magento module that will schedule the execution of MAGMI on a regular basis) and just push the CSV to the import directory (side node: MAGMI could even connect to a remote database server e.g. via ODBC to get its data). This however might depend on your actual requirement and would require rather fundamental questions such as why there is a C#-application needed to execute a MAGMI import profile (which for sure can have its very own valid reason).

Comment: it's working for me  i was just miss the user name and password to add in url Thanks